# What does "did" attribute mean in strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml, string

In one android project: strings.xml,
There is a value like this:

```
<string name="string_one" did="string two">String Demo</string>
```

Does anyone have an idea what the "did" attribute does?

Comment: Do any other values have that because while it doesn't seem to cause any issues, it isn't a used attribute.

Comment: Interesting, not a category in use, but no issue with parsing it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String

Comment: Could you please clarify in which project or tutorial you encountered this? But most likely it will just do nothing and will be ignored, as already mentioned.

Comment: We are doing a big android project, there are many modules. I found one line code like this. But I don't know who wrote it.So I ask here.

Comment: `git blame` and see who did, or just search the project for "did" or "string two", if you're really curious.